# parar un elemento fixed al llegar al final de otro

Tags: html, css

veran tengo un boton flotando a la izquierda de la pantalla, lo que quiero es que al hacer scroll el boton baje o suba siempre que no adelante otro elemento de mas abajo, hasta el momento el boton sigue de largo; este es el código

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

        var desplazamiento_top = $(this).scrollTop(); //get scroll position top scroll_top
        var alto_elemento_parent =  $("#btn_mensaje").parent().outerHeight(); //get high parent element height_element_parent
        var alto_elemento = $("#btn_mensaje").height(); //get high of elemeneto
        var posicion_fixed_max = alto_elemento_parent - alto_elemento; // get the maximum position of the elemen
        var posicion_fixed = desplazamiento_top < 250 ? 250 - desplazamiento_top : posicion_fixed_max > desplazamiento_top ? 0 : posicion_fixed_max - desplazamiento_top ;
        $("#btn_mensaje").css("top",posicion_fixed);

    });
```

https://i.ibb.co/HPzYQX0/ejemplo.png [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola color, a que te refieres a "que no adelante otro elemento de mas abajo", podrías poner una foto o ejemplo más gráfico.

Comment: lo que quiero es que el punto rojo se mueva únicamente entre el cuadro blanco sea que baje o suba con el scroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hice un ejemplo solo con CSS, espero que sea lo que estés buscando.

Explicación:

Hice la clase css llamada `.btn-sticky` y le añadi la propiedad `position: sticky;` que hace que el elemento sea tratado como un elemento relativo hasta que se cruza el limite establecido, en este caso el limite es `top: 20px;`, cuando pasa ese limite se pone como `position: fixed;` hasta que llega al limite de su contenedor padre.

Espero haberlo explicado bien.

Dejo un snippet para que lo pruebes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>

<style>
 .box {
  height: 300px;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 3rem;
  background-color: #2222;
 }

 .box-lg {
  height: 800px;
 }

 .btn-sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
 }
</style>

<body>

 <div class="box">
  <button type="button" class="btn-sticky">botón</button>
 </div>
 <div class="box box-lg">
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: gracias, me funciono :)